# biblatex: No period after book and collection titles

Tags: biblatex, biber

I have been trying to modify existing `biblatex` styles to match the PNAS citation guidelines and I have an issue with the title delimiter.

PNAS expects book and collection citations to be of this format:

`Doe J (<year>) \emph{<booktitle>} (<publisher>: <address>).`

And journal articles of this format:

`Doe J (<year>) <title>. \emph{<journaltitle>} <volume>(<number>):<pagerange>.`

I have managed to achieve most of this with the help Barbara Beeton, percusse and other gurus.

But I haven't figured out how to have journal titles followed by period+space and book/collection titles only by space.

This is what I have so far:

[image: Output]

Apologetically, I am offering a rather long (M)WE containing all the changes I have made so far to achieve this outcome. I do this to avoid a conflict between what I already changed and the solution you suggest.

Also, since I am a `n00b`, please do let me know if I have any silly mistakes in the modifications I have made.

---

## MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@Article{a:agrawal:2001:01,
  title           = {Phenotypic Plasticity in the Interactions and Evolution of Species},
  author          = {Agrawal, Anurag A.},
  journal         = {Science},
  year            = {2001},
  month           = oct,
  volume          = {294},
  number          = {5541},
  pages           = {321--326},
}

@Book{b:darwin:1859:01,
  title           = {On the Origin of Species by Means of Natural Selection or the Preservation of Favoured Species in the Struggle for Life},
  author          = {Darwin, Charles},
  publisher       = {John Murray},
  address         = {London},
  year            = {1859},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[%
  backend=biber,
  useprefix,
  citestyle=numeric,
  bibstyle=authoryear,
  sorting=none,
  firstinits=true,
  uniquename=init,
  terseinits=true,
  dashed=false,
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

%% =============================================================================
%% PNAS Style
%% =============================================================================
  \AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{month}} % Do not show month in bibliography.
  \AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{month}} % Do not show month in citations.

  % Comma-separated authors, last then first name.
  \renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addspace}
  \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
    \ifbibliography{\addcomma\space}{\addspace\&\space}}
  \renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}
  \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}

  % No quotes or italics in titles, except books and collections in italics.
  \DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,
                      thesis,unpublished]{title}{#1}
  \DeclareFieldFormat[book,collection]{title}{\emph{#1}}

  % Journal titles in italics.
  \DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\emph{#1}}
  \DeclareFieldFormat{issuetitle}{\emph{#1}}
  \DeclareFieldFormat{maintitle}{\emph{#1}}

  % Print publisher, then location, separated by comma in parentheses.
  \renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
    \printtext[parens]{%
      \printlist{publisher}%
      \iflistundef{location}
        {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
        {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
      \printlist{location}%
      \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
      \usebibmacro{date}%
    }\newunit%
  }

  % Remove "in:" for article entries.
  \renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
    \ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

  % Remove page prefixes.
  \DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}

  % Print volume, followed by number in parentheses.
  \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
  \renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
    \printfield{volume}%
    \printfield{number}}

  % Colon for volume(number):pages delimiter.
  \renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{%
    \ifentrytype{article}{\addcolon}{\addcomma\space}}

  % Add labelnumbers to bibliography.
  \DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{#1\adddot}
  \defbibenvironment{bibliography}
    {\list
       {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
        \printfield{prefixnumber}%
        \printfield{labelnumber}}}
       {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
        \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
        \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
        \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
        \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
        \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
    {\endlist}
    {\item}

  % Omit authoryear disambiguation.
  \AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{extrayear}}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

therefor you have to modify the bibdriver for the entrytype `book` in `standard.bbx`. You can easily exchange parts from macros, especially biblatex-macros, with the package `xpatch`.

Add the following lines to your preamble, it will exchange the first string with the second - which will replace the default unit at this time for one time with a space character.

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibdriver{book}{\newunit\newblock\usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}}{%
\setunit{\addspace}\newblock%
\usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
}{}{}
```

Comment: btw. it's easier if you write the wanted format like: Doe J (year) _booktitle_ (publisher: address). - much easier to read.

Comment: @sudosensei, would you mind sharing you the biblatex PNAS style, if you have it working?