# No period between article name and journal, {article}-only (authoryear-ibid)

Tags: biblatex, formatting

my department has very specific expectations for formatting the Works Cited.
Usually, most parts are to be delimited (by a period, a comma, a colon…). I got around most of the issues, but one remains.

For articles, it is to be this:

```
Last Name, First Name. Year. “Title of Article.” Title of Book. Ed. Name(s) of editor(s). Place: Publisher. Pages of article.
```

Note how the period between Title of Article and Title of Book is missing. It is to be inside the article title. I can easily insert that one into my bib-file, but I would then have to get rid of the one that author year-comp sets.

So far I fiddled around with `\xpatch` with hints from [biblatex: No period after book and collection titles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180986/biblatex-no-period-after-book-and-collection-titles), but I can’t seem to get it to work. I also looked in `standard.bbx` for anything that looks like what I’m looking for but I cannot seem to find anything.

Please find attached my `.tex`-file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xpatch}
     \usepackage{csquotes}
     \usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=american]{english}
     \usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
     \usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid,backend=biber,doi=false,isbn=false,url=false,autolang=hyphen]{biblatex}
     \addbibresource{Merkliste.bib}
     \renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}
     \renewbibmacro{in:}{\ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}
    \renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{\addspace}
     \renewcommand{\bibpagespunct}{\ifentrytype{incollection}{\addperiod\addspace}{\addcolon\addspace}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}

\xpatchbibmacro{date+extrayear}{%
  \printtext[parens]%
}{%
  \setunit*{\addperiod\space}%
  \printtext%
}{}{}
%\xpatchbibdriver{article}{\newunit\usebibmacro{title}}{%
%\setunit{\addspace}\newunit%
%\usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
%}{}{}

\AtEveryBibitem{\clearlist{language}} % clears language
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{note}}    % clears notes
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{series}}   % clears Series
\AtEveryBibitem{\ifentrytype{book}{\clearfield{number}}{}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\ifentrytype{book}{\clearfield{pages}}{}}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}. 
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Commented out is the part with which I am trying to achieve the correct references.

Here is one example of such a journal in my .bib:

```
@article{conrick_challenges_2006,
    Author = {Conrick, Maeve},
    Date-Modified = {2014-08-03 13:33:04 +0000},
    Doi = {10.1386/ijfs.9.3.311_1},
    Issn = {13682679},
    Journal = {International Journal of Francophone Studies},
    Keywords = {{BILINGUALISM}, Bill 101, {CANADA}, {CONFEDERATION}, 1867, Education, {FEDERAL} government, francophone, French, {GOVERNMENT} policy, {HISTORY}, {LANGUAGE} \& languages, language policy, linguistic duality, minority language communities, official languages, Quebec},
    Month = dec,
    Number = {3},
    Pages = {311--328},
    Shorttitle = {The challenges of linguistic duality for francophone Canada},
    Title = {The challenges of linguistic duality for francophone Canada: contact, conflict and continuity},
    Url = {http://www.redi-bw.de/db/ebsco.php/search.ebscohost.com/login.aspx%3fdirect%3dtrue%26db%3daph%26AN%3d24405708%26site%3dehost-live},
    Urldate = {2014-07-26},
    Volume = {9},
    Year = {2006}}
```

[image: output]

Comment: This can most likely be dealt with by using `csquotes` and using the `american` quoting style. It would be much easier if you could provide us with a proper [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), preferably with an example `.bib` entry and your relevant modifications.

Comment: I edited the question. Sorry for the rather massive MWE, but I felt I had to get all my edits in. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is actually the default if your language setting is (recognised as) American. Then `biblatex` tries to use American punctuation rules and would move the full stop inside the quotation marks.

Unfortunately, `polyglossia` support is still a bit shaky, so the language variant `american` is not detected (you get plain `english` which is basically `american` without the punctuation setting you want). You will have to enable US-style quotation marks manually with

```
\uspunctuation
```

or

```
\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{\uspunctuation}
```

in your preamble (the latter is what the `biblatex` documentation seems to suggest).

If you use `babel` instead of `polyglossia`, this is done automatically for you, if you use `american`.

Answer (score 1):

I added a patch to the `title` bib macro to do that:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{xpatch}
     \usepackage{csquotes}%[style = american]
     \usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=american]{english}
     \usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
     \usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid,backend=biber,doi=false,isbn=false,url=false,autolang=hyphen]{biblatex}
     \renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}
     \renewbibmacro{in:}{\ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}
    \renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{\addspace}
     \renewcommand{\bibpagespunct}{\ifentrytype{incollection}{\addperiod\addspace}{\addcolon\addspace}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}

\xpatchbibmacro{date+extrayear}{%
  \printtext[parens]%
}{%
  \setunit*{\addperiod\space}%
  \printtext%
}{}{}

\AtEveryBibitem{\clearlist{language}} % clears language
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{note}}    % clears notes
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{series}}   % clears Series
\AtEveryBibitem{\ifentrytype{book}{\clearfield{number}}{}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\ifentrytype{book}{\clearfield{pages}}{}}

%%%%% Patch added
\xpatchbibmacro{title}{\printfield[titlecase]{subtitle}}%
{\printfield[titlecase]{subtitle}\ifentrytype{article}{\addperiod}{}}%
{}{}%

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{conrick_challenges_2006,
    Author = {Conrick, Maeve},
    Date-Modified = {2014-08-03 13:33:04 +0000},
    Doi = {10.1386/ijfs.9.3.311_1},
    Issn = {13682679},
    Journal = {International Journal of Francophone Studies},
    Keywords = {{BILINGUALISM}, Bill 101, {CANADA}, {CONFEDERATION}, 1867, Education, {FEDERAL} government, francophone, French, {GOVERNMENT} policy, {HISTORY}, {LANGUAGE} \& languages, language policy, linguistic duality, minority language communities, official languages, Quebec},
    Month = dec,
    Number = {3},
    Pages = {311--328},
    Shorttitle = {The challenges of linguistic duality for francophone Canada},
    Title = {The challenges of linguistic duality for francophone Canada: contact, conflict and continuity},
    Url = {http://www.redi-bw.de/db/ebsco.php/search.ebscohost.com/login.aspx%3fdirect%3dtrue%26db%3daph%26AN%3d24405708%26site%3dehost-live},
    Urldate = {2014-07-26},
    Volume = {9},
    Year = {2006}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I’m trying to work out what this does (i.e. the syntax). \printfield, I gather, ends the block? titlecase is for printing in title case, I suppose, but where does subtitle come from and what does it do? And what exactly has made the period vanish? Sorry to be a nuisance but I’d like to know :)

Comment: I quite approve your curiosityThe presence of `subtitle` comes from the original `title` macro. I suppose it's there because some titles may have subtitles, and it says how to format them. The patch only adds a full stop before the closing quotes, so that  biblatex doesn't add one after the quotes.